# Assign owner field based on related account team

Tags: apex, class, ownership

I'm trying to figure out the best way to automate the record ownership for a custom object called *PSA_Case__c*.  This object has a lookup field to the Account object (Account__c) and on the Account object it can have 0 or more children AccountTeamMember records whose role name is 'DE'.

**The Requirement:** -

- If there are **0 'DE' account team members** on the related account, assign the PSA_Case__c to a queue.
- If there is **1 'DE' account team member** on the related account, use that UserId and set it to the Owner__c field on the PSA_Case__c record.
- If there are **2 or more 'DE' account team members** on the related account, assign the PSA_Case__c to a queue.

My issue is I'm having a hard time determining the best data collections to use for this use case.  I've attached my code that I have so far - any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public class PSATicketController {
    // I will call this class method in a before insert trigger on the PSA case object

    public void assignDE (List<PSA_Case__c> psaCaseList) {
    System.debug('There are ' + psaCaseList.size() + ' psa cases in the list');

    // Create a set of AccountIds, and store those ID's if the Account__c on the 
    // passed in PSA Case has a value

    ​Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();

    for (PSA_Case__c p : psaCaseList) {
        System.debug('Account Id:' + p.Account__c );
        accountIds.add(p.Account__c);
    }
    System.debug('There are ' + accountIds.size() + ' in the list');

    // Create a list of AccountTeamMembers whose role is 'DE' 
    // and are linked to the accountIds set

    List<AccountTeamMember> accountTeamMemberList = [SELECT Id, AccountId, UserId, TeamMemberRole FROM AccountTeamMember WHERE TeamMemberRole = 'DE' AND AccountId IN :accountIds];
    System.debug('There are ' + accountTeamMemberList.size() + ' team members in the list.');

    // Here's where I need some guidance.  I have the account IDs and I know which accounts have DE roles.  
    // Now I need to come up with the iteration logic to determine the correct assignment.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a grouping structure.

```
Map<Id, List<AccountTeamMember>> accountToTeam = new Map<Id, List<AccountTeamMember>>();
for (AccountTeamMember teamMember : [/*query*/])
{
    if (!accountToTeam.containsKey(teamMember.AccountId))
        accountToTeam.put(teamMember.AccountId, new List<AccountTeamMember>());
    accountToTeam.get(teamMember.AccountId).add(teamMember);
}
for (Id accountId : accountToTeam.keySet())
{
    if (accountToTeam.get(accountId).size() == 1)
    {
        // assign team member
    }
    else
    {
        // assign queue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Adrian's answer, but you can use a sub-query instead:

```
Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>(
    [SELECT (SELECT UserId FROM AccountTeamMembers 
             WHERE TeamMemberRole = 'DE')
     FROM Account
     WHERE Id IN 
         (SELECT Account__c FROM PSA_Case__c WHERE Id IN :psaCaseList)]);
for(PSA_Case__c record: psaCaseList) {
    if(accounts.containskey(record.Account__c)) {
        Account acct = accounts.get(record.Account__c);
        if(acct.AccountTeamMembers.size() == 0) {
            // No records
        } else if(acct.AccountTeamMembers.size() == 1) {
            // Assign acct.AccountTeamMembers[0].UserId
        } else {
            // more than 1 record
        }
    }
}
```

You can use your "accountIds" variable instead if the records may not be saved to the database yet, but it's more efficient to use a query when you can.